# VBA Adding Attachment with using IF Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to code this to send emails to many addresses with different attachments depending on what addressee it is. Unfortunately every time I got **Automation ERROR** on the `ELSE END IF` line

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail()
'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties.

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim body, head, filePath, subject As String
    Dim xyz As Long
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Create e-mail item
    x = 1

    filePath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nowy folder\"
    subject = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"

    For xyz = 1 To 4
        ActiveSheet.Range("f5").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = xyz
        Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        head = "<HTML><BODY><P>Hi " & Cells(xyz, 1).Value & ",</P>"
        body = "<BR /><P>We are looking forward to having you at our <STRONG>Metropolitan Night Football Event</STRONG> this upcoming Sunday, <STRONG>11/17</STRONG>!  Note, that the Giants game time has changed from 8:30 PM to 4:25 PM.</P>"
        With objMail
            .subject = subject
            .To = ActiveSheet.Range("To")
            If Range("f5").Value = "1" Then
                .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 1 tej"
            Else
            End If
            If Range("f5").Value = "2" Then
                .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 2 tej"
            Else
            End If
            If Range("f5").Value = "3" Then
                .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 3 tej"
            Else
            End If
            If Range("f5").Value = "4" Then
                .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 4 tej"
            End If
            .BodyFormat = 2
            .HTMLBody = head & body
            .display
        End With
    Next xyz
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim body, head, filePath, subject As String` does not initiate 4 `String` vars; it creates the first 3 as `Variants` and the last as a `String`.

Comment: @Jeeped: Nice edit !  The initial post was so badly indented I couldn't read it without getting sick.

Answer (score 2):

ElseIf doesn't follow an EndIf

its   If , ElseIf , EndIf

```
If Range("f5").Value = "1" Then
       .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 1 tej"

Elseif Range("f5").Value = "2" Then
       .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 2 tej"

ElseIf Range("f5").Value = "3" Then
       .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 3 tej"

ElseIf Range("f5").Value = "4" Then
       .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 4 tej"
EndIf
```

You can also use Select Case in this circumstance (less code, neater)

```
Select Case Range("f5").Value

       Case 1
               .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 1 tej"
       Case 2
               .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 2 tej"
       Case 3
               .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 3 tej"
       Case 4
               .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 4 tej"

 End Select
```

But for the smallest code you would just write

```
 .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 " &  Range("f5").Value & " tej"
```

Comment: Perhaps `Case 1, 2, 3, 4  .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 " & Range("f5").Value & " tej"`.

Comment: whats the need for Case 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: Just error control to make sure that the `Range("f5").Value` is within the set of {1,2,3,4} and you are not trying to attach something that might not exist. Cannot write it out in full here but it would replace the 4 `Case` conditions while remaining inside `Select Case ... End Select`.

Comment: So far so good gents :) thanks a lot. The next problem is that i want to attach more than 1 file to every email. What should I do then?

Comment: .attachments.add can be called multiple times just make sure to check the sizes so that the total is not over 3mb to ensure delivery on most networks

Comment: The other problem is i got run time erro 440 Automation Error on the attachemnt adding line or ElseiF. Nearly to get sick about that lads.

Comment: As you can see the  For xyz = 1 To 4 (in testing but in future gonna be over 39) changing the value in F5 cell. When the value is changed i want to get other recipent and other attachments.